# best data structure to resolve dependencies between tasks

Tags: data-structures, tree, dependencies

I am developing a code for a robot which is supposed to make a product.
The process is composed of many tasks. each task may or may not depend on other tasks. I am wondering if there is a better approach than using trees or it's the perfect data structure for it.

Comment: Sounds like a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), not a tree to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) for your use-case.

To determine the order of execution of your tasks, you could use a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on the DAG.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Adjoint set Datastructure. By using Union find you can resolve dependencies and find an ordered path. Besides that the Time complexity of Adding or removing an element from an Adjoint set is O(1) hence it will take care of the changing requirement